# Issue with PayPal Recurring Payments Profile

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout, paypal-nvp, nvp

I am working with PayPal NVP to create a subscription-based service, where I will be accepting payments via PayPal and the type of payment is going to be Recurring Payments.

This is my `signup.php` page:

```
//SetExpressCheckout
$sec_data = array(
    'USER'                           => PAYPAL_API_USERNAME,
    'PWD'                            => PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD,
    'SIGNATURE'                      => PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE,
    'VERSION'                        => "95.0",
    'METHOD'                         => "SetExpressCheckout",
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'           => $total_amt,
    'RETURNURL'                      => "<url_structure>",
    'CANCELURL'                      => "<url_structure>",
    'NOSHIPPING'                     => "1",
    'SOLUTIONTYPE'                   => "Sole",
    'LOGOIMG'                        => "<url_structure>",
    'BRANDNAME'                      => "My Website",
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'  => "USD",
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'       => $current_plan_price,
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => "Sale",
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'        => $current_plan_price,
    'L_BILLINGTYPE0'                 => "RecurringPayments",
    'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0' => "You'll be billed USD ".$total_amt.".",
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'          => "You'll be billed USD ".$total_amt.".",
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM'        => "Thank you for your payment!",
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM'        => "INV-".$invoice_num,
    'NOTETOBUYER'                    => $current_plan_name,
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREASON' => "None",
    'EMAIL'                          => $email,
    'LANDINGPAGE'                    => "Billing",
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT'        => $tax_amt,
    'L_PAYMENTTYPE0'                 => "InstantOnly"
);

//GetExpressCheckoutDetails
$get_ec_data = array(
    'USER'      => PAYPAL_API_USERNAME,
    'PWD'       => PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD,
    'SIGNATURE' => PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE,
    'TOKEN'     => $ec_token,
    'METHOD'    => "GetExpressCheckoutDetails",
    'VERSION'   => "95.0"
);

//DoExpressCheckoutPayment
$decp_data = array(
    'USER'                          => PAYPAL_API_USERNAME,
    'PWD'                           => PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD,
    'SIGNATURE'                     => PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE,
    'METHOD'                        => "DoExpressCheckoutPayment",
    'TOKEN'                         => $ec_token,
    'PAYERID'                       => $ec_response['PAYERID'],
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'          => $total_amt,
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => "USD",
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'      => $total_amt,
    'VERSION'                       => "95.0"
);

//CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
$crpp_array = array(
    'USER'               => PAYPAL_API_USERNAME,
    'PWD'                => PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD,
    'SIGNATURE'          => PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE,
    'VERSION'            => "95.0",
    'METHOD'             => "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile",
    'TOKEN'              => $ec_token,
    'PROFILESTARTDATE'   => $last_payment_date,
    'DESC'               => "You'll be billed USD ".$total_amt.".",
    'BILLINGPERIOD'      => "Month",
    'BILLINGFREQUENCY'   => "12",
    'TOTALBILLINGCYCLES' => '0',
    'AMT'                => $total_amt,
    'CURRENCYCODE'       => "USD",
    'EMAIL'              => $get_cx_data['cx_email'],
    'STREET'             => "Bedford Ave",
    'CITY'               => "Brooklyn",
    'STATE'              => "New York",
    'COUNTRYCODE'        => "US",
    'ZIP'                => "11211"
);

//GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails
$grppd_array = array(
    'USER'      => PAYPAL_API_USERNAME,
    'PWD'       => PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD,
    'SIGNATURE' => PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE,
    'VERSION'   => "95.0",
    'METHOD'    => 'GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails',
    'PROFILEID' => $get_crpp_response['PROFILEID']
);
```

And I am sending the nvp data to PayPal like this:

```
toPayPal($nvp_data, "https://api-3t." .(PAYPAL_MODE == 'TEST' ? 'sandbox.paypal' : 'paypal'). ".com/nvp");
```

Now the issue is that everything seems to be working on Sandbox but when it comes to Live, the Recurring Account is not being created on my main PayPal account.

Is there anything that I am missing? Also, do I need to install NVP SDK or something, I have no idea about it.

Also, in the sandbox, when I am running `print_r()` on the response of `GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` the `PROFILESTARTDATE` and `NEXTPAYMENTDATE` are the same. Is that the issue?

Here are the PayPal functions that I am using on my `paypal-functions.php` page:

```
function toPayPal($inputArray, $PayPalURL) {
        $nvp_post_data_str   = '';

        foreach($inputArray as $key => $value) {
            $nvp_post_data_str .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
        }

        $nvp_post_data_str = substr($nvp_post_data_str, 0, strlen($nvp_post_data_str) - 1);
        $ch = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $PayPalURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_post_data_str);
        $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        
        //$httpResponse;
        
        $httpResponse = explode('&', $httpResponse);
        
        for($i = 0; $i < count($httpResponse); $i++) {
            $temp_array = explode('=', $httpResponse[$i]);
            $httpResponseArray[$temp_array[0]] = urldecode($temp_array[1]);
        }
        
        return $httpResponseArray;
    }
```

Am I missing out on any `curl` code on the `paypal-functions.php` page or something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I tried reading the PayPal NVP documentation as well and whatever I coded is based on that. I am not sure why everything is working on Sandbox and not on Live mode.

On Sandbox, when I am running `print_r()` on the response of `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` method, I am getting these values:

```
[PROFILEID] => I-SXK4UUEV0M0J
[PROFILESTATUS] => ActiveProfile
[ACK] => Success
```

and I am able to capture the `profileid` in my database as well.

However, when I am switching to Live mode, the same code is able to create a recurring profile on my PayPal business account. Also, in my database, the `profileid` column in not being populated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using the legacy/deprecated NVP API? It is very old. See the current subscriptions documentation, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/ .  You can generate a button in the account interface, for sandbox https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans

Comment: I have an admin panel designed which I want to give to the user after a successful signup. I want to be able to get the user's data that I have been collecting on the `signup.php` page and basically give a customized admin panel based on that data. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The end goal makes sense enough, but using the NVP API for subscriptions in 2023 does not make sense

Comment: I know, but this is how I am "supposed" to make it work. Can you please help me in this case?

Comment: Seems like a waste of time, but at the least you'll need to log and show the example request+response that's failing (in live) in your question

Comment: Is there any other way of doing it, keeping my requirements constant? PayPal subscription offers hassle-free integration, however, I am not quite sure if that's going to serve my purpose. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: The Subscriptons REST API is newer and better than the classic recurring payments profile NVP API in every way, and generating a working Subscriptions plan/button (via the account interface) is far simpler. Integrate a webhook  listener for each client-id and subscribe it to the event `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` afterward. Use `custom_id` if you need to send any additional metadata at createSubscription time, such as which user it is for.

Comment: Sounds a bit complicated, but will give it a try. Thanks!